# Changing the background color of a Wiki page in SharePoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, jquery, wiki

Can't find anything specific on this on Google, but I am looking to find a way to change the default white background color of the main content area in an individual SharePoint 2007 wiki page.  I have to be able to do this using **only** the web browser functionality.  I **do not** have access to SharePoint Designer nor the ability to access any of the actual HTML/ASPX files on the SharePoint server.

I thought jQuery could do the trick via this snippet:

```
<script src="path/to/jquery-x.y.z.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("#MSO_ContentTable").css("background-color","black");
});
</script>
```

But because SP2007 only allows you to add a CEWP at the bottom of an individual wiki page, my guess is the javascript doesn't load in time to modify the CSS property and flip the page's color.  The white is just way too harsh on the eyes.

Can this be done with the limited editing powers that I have?

Comment: Q: did you loaded the jQuery library before trying that function? without it, it won't really work!

Comment: Yes, I just didn't include it in the example I gave.  It is loaded in a `<script>` tag just prior to the line of code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try adding the following CSS:

> .ms-rte-layoutszone-inner {
>        background-color: #000000; }

or jquery with the selector using the aforementioned div.

Comment: No idea if this actually solves the problem, as I determined that I didn't need to modify the background after all.  I'll give points for effort, though.